# How remove all reocuuring dynamic elements using vanilla JavaScipt?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an element that is dynamically rendered and do it when an element exists, or is rendered again. This is the method written to achieve that:

```js
function removePopup(){
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("DialogBox");
    elem[0].remove();
}
```

This will remove the element but if the element is rendered again function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is deleting only the first element of an array and only once. If you want to delete every element with class "DialogBox", then loop and delete them.

```
function removePopup() {
 let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".DialogBox");
 for (let i in elems) elems[i].remove();
}
```

If you want to delete them multiple times, then you should use eg. addEventlistener or setInterval.

```
function removePopup() {
 let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("DialogBox");
 elem[0].remove();
}

addEventListener("click", () => removePopup());

// ---------- //

function removeEveryPopup() {
 let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".DialogBox");
 for (let i in elems) elems[i].remove();
}

addEventListener("click", () => removeEveryPopup());
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

If you wanna delete a specific element, give it a unique id and target it by id.

```
function removePopup() {
 let elem = document.querySelector("#elementId");
 elem.remove();
}

addEventListener("click", () => removePopup());
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thank you for your effort and time, Jason.
I also tried to loop over the elements yes indeed it will delete the element but when the element(asynchronous) is rendered again my function is useless. and also event listener is not applicable in my case I want my script to always watch if the element is existing. I am planning to use setInterval(), But I think it will affect the performance.